# C++ error: double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: c++, vector

I'd like to know why the following program gets the error "double free or corruption (fasttop)" when I run the program. I know I can use string instead of character array. But I'd like to use character array with dynamic memory allocation. Could you please let me know how I can fix this problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Cube
{
public:
    char *str;

    Cube(int len)
    {
        str = new char[len+1];
    }

    Cube(const Cube &c)
    {
        str = new char[strlen(c.str) + 1];
        strcpy(str, c.str);
    }   
    ~Cube()
    {
        delete [] str;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector <Cube> vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char in [] = "hello !!";
        Cube c(strlen(in)+1);
        strcpy(c.str, in);
        vec.push_back(c);
    } 

    int i = 0;
    for ( vector<Cube>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); )
    {
        cout << it->str << endl;
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            it = vec.erase(it);
        else
            it++;
    }


    for ( vector<Cube>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->str << endl;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: I don't get any such error when compiling and running this code in MinGW on Windows.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using g++ on Ubuntu. I have overloaded the assignment operator. Now it works fine.

Comment: Ok.  Yeah, I was getting corrupted data when I ran my program but adding the assignment operator seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot to define `operator=` for your class. This is the rule of Big Three (copy ctor, dtor, assignment must all be defined).

Comment: From c++references: Adds a new element at the end of the vector, after its current last element. The content of this new element is initialized to a copy of x.

Comment: Excellent !! I implemented the assignment operator (operator=) and it works perfect. many thanks !!!

Answer (score 6):

n.m. has already given a fine answer, but I found this question interesting so I decided to try to understand it a little better.

It turns out then when you call `erase()` on the first item of an iterator (which we will call `item0`), here's what the iterator does: it uses the `=` operator of your class to do `item0 = item1`.  Then it deletes `item1`.

If you don't define your own `=` operator, I think it will simply copy the memory of your object over from `item1` to `item0`, so `item0` and `item1` will temporarily be pointing to the same string.  Then when `item1` gets deleted, the string gets freed, leaving `item0` in an invalid state because it has a pointer to memory that has been freed.

Here is some simple test code that reproduces and illuminates the problem:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Cube
{
public:
    char * str;

    Cube(const Cube &c) { set(c.str); }
    Cube(const char * s) { set(s); }
    ~Cube() { clear(); }  // is "delete []" necessary?  not sure

#if 1    // change to 0 to cause a bug
    void operator=(const Cube &c)
    {
        clear();   // necessary to avoid memory leaks
        printf("operator=\n");
        set(c.str);
    }
#endif

private:
    void set(const char * s)
    {
        str = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
        printf("allocated %p for %s\n", str, s);
        strcpy(str, s);
    }

    void clear()
    {
        if (str)
        {
             printf("freeing %p: %s\n", str, str);
             delete str;
        }
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("== CREATING VECTOR ==\n");
    vector <Cube> vec;
    vec.push_back(Cube("octopus"));
    vec.push_back(Cube("squid"));

    printf("== BEGINNING ITERATION ==\n");
    vector<Cube>::iterator it = vec.begin();
    printf("First entry is %p %s\n", it->str, it->str);
    it = vec.erase(it);
    printf("Second entry is %p %s\n", it->str, it->str);  // this prints garbage if Cube has no = operator
    return 0;    
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
== CREATING VECTOR ==
allocated 00350F98 for octopus
allocated 00350FB8 for octopus
freeing 00350F98: octopus
allocated 00350F98 for squid
allocated 00350FD8 for squid
allocated 00350FE8 for octopus
freeing 00350FB8: octopus
freeing 00350F98: squid
== BEGINNING ITERATION ==
First entry is 00350FE8 octopus
freeing 00350FE8: octopus
operator=
allocated 00350F98 for squid
freeing 00350FD8: squid
Second entry is 00350F98 squid
freeing 00350F98: squid
```

I compiled and ran this in Windows with MinGW.  The command I used was `g++ -Wl,--enable-auto-import test.cpp && a.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

If it hurts, don't do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Cube
{
public:
    string str;

    Cube(const string& s) : str(s) { }
};

int main()
{
    vector <Cube> vec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char in [] = "hello !!";
        vec.push_back(Cube(in));
    } 

    int i = 0;
    for ( vector<Cube>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); )
    {
        cout << it->str << endl;
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            it = vec.erase(it);
        else
            it++;
    }


    for ( vector<Cube>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it < vec.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->str << endl;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Happens to be shorter and correct (not tested).